# virtual host / apache2 / ssl configuration - auto redirect from 80 to 443 not working - bad request 400 error

Tags: networking, server, apache2, ssl

This problem has cost me a few hours trying to fix and I simply have no clue - so huge thanks in advance to anyone that can help me solve this.

This is the Bad Request 400 error I get:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

And this is my vhosts file:

```
<Directory /var/www/sub1>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  sub1.site1.com
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub1.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/chain.pem
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's the strange part - as long as I specify port 80 at the end of the URL - it works fine.
If I DON'T type in http:// at the front of the URL - it works fine.
-BUT-
If I type in http://sub1.site1.com - it throws the above error.

I'm not sure if my apache2 config or the fact that I used certbot on my ubuntu server has something to do with this odd error, but I've tried everything I can think of to fix it.

So why would:

```
sub1.site1.com
sub1.site1.com:443
https://sub1.site1.com
http://sub1.site1.com:80
```

All work just fine, but

```
http://sub1.site1.com
```

Throw the above error rather than just automatically redirecting to one of the 4 url's that work fine?

Comment: Please review how other people format details in their posts. Then update your post.

Comment: Are you entering the URL in a browser or via a CLI tool? If a CLI tool show the entire command.

Comment: Run the following command. Post the command and output in your post. `curl -v -L http://sub1.site1.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove your existing Virtualhost conf file which you have created.
Then create a new file `site1.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` folder

```bash
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo nano site1.conf
```

Write the `site1.conf` file as below -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub1.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <Directory /var/www/sub1>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName sub1.site1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.site1.com/chain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Enable the virtualhost conf file, disable default configuration file and restart the apache service

```bash
cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
sudo a2ensite site1.conf
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Hope your problem will get solved.